# To MP4V, or to DX50, or not to be

Tags: encoding, mpeg, mpeg4

Should i compress my final outputs down to FOURCC of DX50 or MP4V?  Tis the question.  I'm having a hard time deciding on this, since im not really sure what to expect in future technology development.

I do want mac compatibility lending support to MP4V, i do run windows almost exclusively lending support to DX50, and there is a nice feature in DVD players playing divx files which think also supports DX50(among others, incluging DIVX)

However i can give a flying crap about dvd player support for the most part because i did away with using those 'Circular Silver' things altogether for audio and video media, on all fronts.

What i really want is only future compatibility, and playibility by any operating system in 10-25 years, and i only want to use either DX50(ill consider DIVX, but prefer the newer), or MP4V.

CONS of MP4V, dvd player compatibility, and what else???

CONS of DX50, no native MAC support(i might not be here in 20 years to explain to my children and grandchildren how to install alternative legacy players to play all my "old crap")

Trying to avoid becoming Legacy..

MP4V?  or DX50??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just a matter of which FOURCC to assign, and not the codec, then choose `MP4V` since it has broader compatibility, and the tag can always be changed later, using a tool like ffmpeg i.e.

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -c copy -map 0 -vtag DX50 tagged.avi
```